# React PropTypes with typescript template literal Types

Tags: typescript, react-proptypes

Typescript 4.1 allowing using [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) which can be used to simulate simple regex patterns, so I could assert certain types of strings and not any string.

Let's say that I have the following type:

```js
type percentStr = `${number}%`;
type relativeOrAbsStr = number | `${number | percentStr}${number | ''}`;
```

Can be a number, a number-string followed by % and optionally another number after:

example ok: `33`(number),`'33%'`,`'10%330'`,`'500%30'`
example error: `'23'`(string-number not followed by %)

However - PropTypes complain if a try to use PT.string as an option because this type cannot be any string, it should be a string of a certain shape.

```
import PT from 'prop-types';
type myStr:relativeOrAbsStr = PT.oneOfType([PT.string, PT.number])
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'relativeOrAbsStr'.
```

Currently, as a workaround I use `as any` assertion:

```
type myStr:myStr:relativeOrAbsStr = PT.oneOfType([PT.string as any, PT.number]),
```

How do I define an appropriate prop-types type for my template string literal type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can provide custom validator function to check propType:

```
const pAnchorString = (props, propName, componentName) => {
  if (!/^\d+%?\d*$/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error('Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' + ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.');
  }
};
```

this will validate against '10','10%','10%10' but not 's','10s' etc